# Electrification in highspeed train

Tags: electrical-engineering

I have some questions about overhead line and substation equipment in high speed line.
My first question is about if all the overhead voltage is the same for all the intervals of speed? I mean for 250, 300 and 350 Km/h is it 25 Kv?
My second question is about if we want to increase speed of line, for example, after 5 years, should we change all these equipment  related to its consumable power? Since when the speed increases, it needs more power? What can we do to have a cost-effective solution?

Thank you in advance

Comment: In what country? I know of countries having multiple overhead voltages. 1 for the main net, 1 for the high-speed train and 1 near the border because the border country is using a different voltage.

Comment: If the supply is 25kV, then to change power, why not just absorb more current?